# cout in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-c++

When I attempt to compile the following

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#include "stdafx.h"  // This was included by Visual Studio 


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])  // The name _tmain was generated by Visual Studio
{
    int a = 1;
    cout << a << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I get a compiler message:

```
warning C4627: '#include <iostream>': skipped when looking for precompiled header use
                Add directive to 'StdAfx.h' or rebuild precompiled header
```

Then I'm told that `cout` is undefined. (It doesn't help to write `std::cout`.)

I'm using a default Visual Studio projects. This is the first time I've used this. Suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int a=10;
    cout << a << "\n";
    cin>>a;
    return 0;
}
```

Slam dear! I have written the same code, but only changing the order of first three line. It gives result at console without any error or warning. Please check it.

Answer (score 2):

Put your iostream include and the std namespace declaration *after* the stdafx.h include.  The program will then compile and run.

As to why, my guess is that precompiled headers (enabled by default) rely on the exact sequence of #include directives.  Putting iostream first means that the PCH for stdafx no longer matches the actual sequence of declarations known to the compiler at that point.

Comment: Thanks. Putting  #include "stdafx.h"  first fixed the problem.  Another question. Is there a way to get the output to appear in one of the Visual Basic subwindows (as in eclipse) rather than in a CommandPrompt window?  And finally how do you even get a program to run?  All I could see what a run-to-cursor option in the right pop-up menu. There must be a way simply to say run.

Comment: You made a command-line project so it runs in a command prompt window. I have no idea what you mean by "Visual Basic subwindow". To run the program just hit F5 or Ctrl+F5 -- see the Debug menu in Visual Studio.